# Can't compile sub class that implements abstract method from base class

Tags: java

Having problems compiling sub classes of a base class that I've defined that has a single method and each sub class implements the abstract base method, but javac is saying that they don't even though it is quite clearly defined in the sub class.

**DbModel.java (the base class)**

```
package com.manodestra.db;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public abstract class DbModel<T extends DbModel> extends Model {
    abstract T newInstance(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}
```

DbModel extends Model, which only has a generic toString method.

**MenuPermissions.java (the sub class)**

```
package com.manodestra.csa.db.model.configNew;

import com.manodestra.db.DbModel;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class MenuPermissions extends DbModel<MenuPermissions> {
    private final String menuId;
    private final String userLevel;

    public MenuPermissions(
        String menuId,
        String userLevel
    ) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
        this.userLevel = userLevel;
    }

    public String getMenuId() {
        return this.menuId;
    }

    public String getUserLevel() {
        return this.userLevel;
    }

    public MenuPermissions newInstance(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        return new MenuPermissions(
            rs.getString("menu_id"),
            rs.getString("user_level")
        );
    }
}
```

**Compilation Error**

```
[javac] Compiling 487 source files to C:\Media\Code\manodestra_java\bin
[javac] C:\Media\Code\manodestra_java\src\com\manodestra\csa\db\model\configNew\MenuPermissions.java:10:
error: MenuPermissions is not abstract 
and does not override abstract method newInstance(ResultSet) in DbModel
[javac] public class MenuPermissions extends DbModel<MenuPermissions> {
[javac]        ^
```

Anyone see what the problem is here? I'm guessing that I'm overlooking something really simple.

Further info on requirements:

I'm building an entity framework that generates model objects from a given database. MenuPermissions above is one such model object (auto-generated by a class that I've written called GenerateModel). I want each model to have a method that will allow me to get a new instance of each objecct type based on a resultset, which will populate the object accordingly and return it. Ideally, it should be a static method, but I've tried it as a concrete method for the moment as I need to enforce its existence in each sub class of DbModel. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your abstract method has package access, I don't know if that was intended

Comment: @Laser Yep... Post it as an answer. Thumbs up.

Comment: Access level can be widened when overriding: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fIWznf)

Comment: Missing @Override annotation?

Comment: @JornVernee This is true only when the subclass itself has access to the abstract method. This is not the case here, as `MenuPermissions` is not in the `com.manodestra.db` package.

Comment: @MouseEvent Yep ;) I'm used to eclipse's error message, which actually mentions that it's not accessible.

Comment: Adding `@Override` didn't fix the issue. I need these generated classes to be in a different package from the base class. What do I need to do to allow this to happen? I have tried putting them in the same package and it works, but that's not what I need unfortunately.

Comment: I can smell another error coming up as you 're using an instance method `MenuPermissions.newInstance` to instantiate the instance itself.

Comment: @Laser Yeah, I'm still working on this code. It's a work in progress. And this particular bit of compilation just got me stuck. At the moment, the design doesn't make sense, I agree.

Comment: If I could override a static method, then I'd do it that way, but Java doesn't allow that obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your abstract method `newInstance` has package access. I don't know if that was intended but if it is in a different package then you would get an error.

Edit:

So the abstract method in the parent class can not be resolved since it is not declared a `public`. A possible remedy is to add `public` to the method definition or move the child class into the same package as the parent class :-D

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to correct this? I need the generated classes to be in a different package. I have tried placing them in the same package and it works fine, but this is no good to me.

Comment: @ManoDestra Simply put, make the abstract method `protected`.

Comment: Ah, got it. Stupid schoolboy error. Making it public fixes it. Thanks.